# How to properly use an IF and GOTO statement

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, goto

I have zero experience with writing batch files but my goal does not seem difficult. I'm trying to write a small script that will prompt a user to enter an ID number and then search a directory of .jpgs and copy any pictures containing the ID number to a separate directory. The .jpgs are names xxxxxx_zzz.jpg where xxxxxx is the ID number up to 6 digits and zzz is the sequence number. For example, one ID can have many pictures: 123456_001.jpg, 123456_002.jpg, 123456_003.jpg, etc.

I've played with several `IF` and `GOTO` commands, but I seem to be diverging from my goal. I know the two `IF` statements I currently am using below are garbage, but I left them in the syntax to convey the direction I think I should be moving in.

I can't get the `IF` statements to use the `GOTO` commands. I also don't think I fully understand how labels are supposed to work.

```
   @ECHO OFF
   CLS
:START
   DEL /q C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\temp\*.*
:GETINPUT
   set /p propkey=Enter the Property Key of pictures to retrieve.:
   IF EXIST C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\photos\*%propkey%_???.jpg GOTO Success
   IF "%propkey%"=="" ECHO No Property Key was entered. GOTO START
:Success
   ECHO Pictures from Property Key %propkey% will now be moved to the Temp folder on the Desktop. && PAUSE
   COPY "C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\photos\*%propkey%*.jpg" "C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\temp\"
   START C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\temp\
:END
```

Comment: @npocmaka IF EXIST does indeed support wildcards for file names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
:Start
   @echo off
   cls
   :: store source folder
   set _sd=C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\photos
   :: store target folder
   set _td=C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\temp
:CheckFolders
   if not exist %_sd% echo Source folder not found.&goto End
   if not exist %_td% echo Target folder not found.&goto End
   :: wipe target folder
   del /q %_td%\*.*
:GetKey
   set /p _key=Enter the property key:
   if '%_key'=='' echo No property key entered. Please retry.&goto GetKey
   if not exist "%_sd%\*%_key%*.jpg" echo No photos matched the key.&goto End
   echo Copying pictures to %_td%...
   copy "%_sd%\*%_key%*.jpg" "%_td%"
:OpenFolder
   start "%windir%\explorer.exe" "%_td%"
:End
```

A label is a way to arbitrarily designate a line in a batch file. It is used by the `GOTO` command to change the usual top-to-bottom progression of command execution, specifying which line should be processed next.  As you probably figured out, using `IF` commands in unison with `GOTO` allows for conditional processing, such as when values are met or errors are encountered.

Another use of a label could be for documentation or clarity.  In my example above, "CheckFolders" isn't used by a `GOTO`, but it lets the programmer hint at what that section of code does.

Answer (score 1):

Although wild-cards do works in `if exist`, there are certain combinations that may fail. Also, you must enclose the name in quotes if the path may contain spaces. Try:

```
IF EXIST "C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\photos\*%propkey%_*.jpg" GOTO Success

IF "%propkey%"=="" ECHO No Property Key was entered. & GOTO START
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code was very close.  It needed a `goto :eof` to stop it falling through to the main routine. Change `&&` to `&` and an `&` after the echo statement was missing.  I changed the `goto start` to the next label, to avoid a harmless error message.

```
   @ECHO OFF
   CLS
:START
   DEL /q C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\temp\*.*
:GETINPUT
   set /p propkey=Enter the Property Key of pictures to retrieve.:
   IF EXIST "C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\photos\*%propkey%_???.jpg" GOTO Success
   IF "%propkey%"=="" ECHO No Property Key was entered. & GOTO GETINPUT
   goto :EOF
:Success
   ECHO Pictures from Property Key %propkey% will now be moved to the Temp folder on the Desktop. & PAUSE
   COPY "C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\photos\*%propkey%*.jpg" "C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\temp\"
   start "" "C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\temp"
:END
```