# syntax for testing TASKKILL's errorlevel

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, taskkill, tasklist

What is the correct syntax for testing the `errorlevel` of `TASKKILL` in the context of the batch file shown below?

```
:Launch
   start "CloseMe" "C:\Program Files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe" "file://C:\ProgramData\Schneider Electric\Citect SCADA 2016\User\1173051_SM_STP\Files\Stony Mountain Institute Lift Station.html"
   TIMEOUT 1 & 
:ShiftFocus
   wscript "C:\ProgramData\Schneider Electric\Citect SCADA 2016\User\1173051_SM_STP\Files\SendAltTab.vbs"
   TASKKILL /IM iexplore.exe /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq CloseMe - Internet Explorer"
   if %errorlevel% == 1 GOTO ShiftFocus
:End
exit
```

I'm trying to get my batch file to run `TASKKILL` then test the result.

If the result is "INFO: No tasks running with the specified criteria." I need the batch file to try `TASKKILL` again.

If the result is "SUCCESS: Sent termination signal to ... ." I need the batch file to close.

To accomplish this I'm using if statements, labels and gotos which I learned about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20531548/how-to-properly-use-an-if-and-goto-statement) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14691494/check-if-command-was-successful-in-a-batch-file).

I'm suspect I'm using errorlevel incorrectly because no matter what `TASKKILL` does its errorlevel, from my batch files perspective, is 0.  Some answers to similar posts are using `%errorlevel%` and others are using `errorlevel`.  No matter which I use in my batch file its sees an error level of 0 regardless of the actual result of `TASKKILL`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `taskkill` *clears* `ErrorLevel` when you have provided a filter `/FI` which results in no match! However, when you only filter for image names (`/IM`) or process IDs (`/PID`), `ErrorLevel` becomes set to `128` if no matches have been encountered.

Therefore I would prefilter the processes by `tasklist` and use `taskkill` together with its `/PID` filter:

```cmd
:LOOP
rem // Establish a short wait time to not heavily load the processor:
> nul timeout /T 1 /NOBREAK
rem // Prefilter processes and retrieve the PID of the applicable one:
set "PID=" & for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%T in ('
    tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq iexplore.exe" /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq CloseMe - Internet Explorer" /FO LIST
') do if "%%T"=="PID" for /F %%W in ("%%U") do set "PID=%%W"
rem // Loop back in case no PID could be retrieved:
if not defined PID goto :LOOP
rem // Try to kill the task and loop back in case of failure:
taskkill /PID %PID% || goto :LOOP
```

Answer (score 2):

Open a command prompt window and run `if /?`. The output help explains how to correct check for an errorlevel with command **IF** using the syntax `if errorlevel X ...` working since MS-DOS and also within a command block.

`if %errorlevel% == 1 goto ShiftFocus` does not work in a command block starting with `(` and ending with matching `)` as beginners in batch file writing expect because of Windows command processor replaces all occurrences of `%variable%` in entire command block by value of referenced environment variable before the command block is executed at all. This can be seen on running a batch file without `@echo off` from within a command prompt window.

See also [single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) explaining how to evaluate the exit code of a command or application with `if errorlevel X ...` or using the operators `&&` and `||`.

It is also possible to use `if errorlevel 1 if not errorlevel 2 goto ShiftFocus` which means exit code **is greater or equal** `1` but **is not greater or equal** `2`, i.e. like `if ((errorlevel >= 1) && (errorlevel < 2))` in C, C++, C#, JavaScript, etc., in case of an explicit test on exit code `1` is wanted with excluding exit code `128`.

It would be also possible to enable [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) and use it as explained by help of command **SET** output on running `set /?` in a command prompt window with `if !errorlevel! == 1 goto ShiftFocus`. But usage of delayed expansion which can cause other troubles and make batch file processing slower because of double parsing of each command line is really not recommended by me on using it just for evaluation of exit code of a command or application.

However, the real problem is that on Internet Explorer not running the batch file should jump to label `ShiftFocus` according to explanation in question which can be simply achieved by using `if errorlevel 128 goto ShiftFocus`.

So the entire batch file could be:

```
:Launch
start "CloseMe" "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "file://C:\ProgramData\Schneider Electric\Citect SCADA 2016\User\1173051_SM_STP\Files\Stony Mountain Institute Lift Station.html"
%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 1 /NOBREAK >nul

:ShiftFocus
%SystemRoot%\System32\wscript.exe "C:\ProgramData\Schneider Electric\Citect SCADA 2016\User\1173051_SM_STP\Files\SendAltTab.vbs"
%SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe /IM iexplore.exe /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq CloseMe - Internet Explorer"
if errorlevel 128 %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 1 /NOBREAK >nul & goto ShiftFocus

exit /B
```

It is better to use the console applications (external commands) with full path and file extension to make the batch file independent on environment variables `PATH` and `PATHEXT`.

And command `exit` should not be used without option `/B` as it makes testing a batch file very difficult on running it from within a command prompt window instead of double clicking it. See [debugging a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42448601/3074564) for the details.

There is one extra wait for one second added before jumping to `ShiftFocus` and running the script once again because rapidly running the script and `taskkill` in a loop does not make sense to me.

But this batch file does not work for the reason explained by [aschipfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5047996/aschipfl): **TASKKILL** does not exit with value 128 as written by [CatCat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10059074/catcat) on using filter option `/FI` and there is not running process matching the filter.

A language independent solution to work around this quirks of **TASKKILL** was posted by [aschipfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5047996/aschipfl).

A language dependent solution would be using this batch file:

```
:Launch
start "CloseMe" "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "file://C:\ProgramData\Schneider Electric\Citect SCADA 2016\User\1173051_SM_STP\Files\Stony Mountain Institute Lift Station.html"
%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 1 /NOBREAK >nul

:ShiftFocus
%SystemRoot%\System32\wscript.exe "C:\ProgramData\Schneider Electric\Citect SCADA 2016\User\1173051_SM_STP\Files\SendAltTab.vbs"
for /F "delims=:" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe /IM iexplore.exe /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq CloseMe - Internet Explorer"') do if "%%I" == "INFO" %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 1 /NOBREAK >nul & goto ShiftFocus

exit /B
```

The **TASKKILL** command line is executed by **FOR** in a separate command process started with `cmd /C` in background. The line output by **TASKKILL** to handle **STDOUT** in this background command process is captured by **FOR**. Then the captured line is split into substrings using colon as delimiter. The string up to first colon is assigned to loop variable `I`. This string is here language dependent either `INFO` or `SUCCESS`. In case of `INFO` no instance of Internet Explorer was found with window title `CloseMe - Internet Explorer` resulting in a jump to `ShiftFocus` after 1 second and running the VBScript and **TASKKILL** once again.

This Windows language dependent solution should not be used if the batch file should run on any Windows machine with Windows Vista or a later Windows version independent on language of Windows.

Answer (score 1):

```
taskkill /f /im wscript.exe
echo %errorlevel%
pause
```

`%errorlevel%` is

> 0 for success
>
> 1 for Access Denied
>
> 128 for nothing to kill

Comment: When I change the TASKKILL switches to what I need %errorlevel% is always 0

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your filters, when you pipe the output to a `find` command, so you evaluate the errorlevel of `find` instead of the errorlevel of `taskkill`:

```
:ShiftFocus
...
TASKKILL /IM iexplore.exe /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq CloseMe - Internet Explorer" | find "SUCCESS:" && goto :eof
goto :ShiftFocus
```

or

```
:ShiftFocus
...
TASKKILL /IM iexplore.exe /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq CloseMe - Internet Explorer" | find "No tasks running" && goto :ShiftFocus
```